# connect two open triangulate mesh

Tags: 3d, computational-geometry, mesh

I would like ask you how connect two 3d open mesh.
I attach one screenshot with two semisphere triangulate and open.
How can connect them in a single mesh with no holes (a single sphere).
The triangulation of two mesh should remain unchanged (no remesh algorithms).

Thanks in advance.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXHom.png)

Answer (score 0):

**My suggestion:**

Extract the facing outlines, i.e. the polylines formed by the free edges in both triangulation.

Then you will triangulate the space between them in a greedy way. Start by the closest pair, then choose to progress on one outline or the other, depending on the move which gives the less skewed triangles.

Comment: can you explain better the triangulation algorithms? Exist some standard algorithm to connect two open mesh?

Comment: @user1746397: just zigzag between the edges.